# Multi parameter Metropolis-Hastings

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-analysis, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I need to formulate a multi parameter Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.

My question is related to how to define the condition to accept or not the candidate value.

In my problem (it is a curve fitting) I have 5 parameters $\theta=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$, some of them are associated to a informative Prior distribution, others to a non-informative Prior distribution.

PRIOR DISTRIBUTIONS:

- $a_1 \sim$  Log-Normal$(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$
- $a2 \sim$  Log-Normal$(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$
- $a3 \sim$ Uniform(lower3,upper3)
- $a4 \sim$ Uniform(lower4,upper4)
- $a_5 \sim$ Uniform(lower5,upper5)

Moreover I calculate the likelihood estimation for the parameters, lets call it Like($\theta$).

To decide if to accept or not the candidate value at time *t*, I have in mind three options, but I don't know which one is correct, because I could find only algorithms with 1 parameter:

- define the ratio R for each parameter:

$R_i=\frac{Like(\theta)_t Prior(a_i)_t}{Like(\theta)_{t-1} Prior(a_i)_{t-1}}$

and accept the vector theta at time *t* only if ALL the $R_i$ are higher than 1 or than a random number between 0 and 1.

- define the ratio R for each parameter:

$R_i=\frac{Like(\theta)_t Prior(a_i)_t}{Like(\theta)_{t-1} Prior(a_i)_{t-1}}$

and accept the parameter $a_i$ at time *t* if the $R_i$ are higher than 1 or than a random number between 0 and 1.

- define the ratio R as:

$R=\frac{Like(\theta)_t Prior(a_1)_t Prior(a_2)_t Prior(a_3)_t Prior(a_4)_t Prior(a_5)_t}{Like(\theta)_{t-1} Prior(a_1)_{t-1} Prior(a_2)_{t-1} Prior(a_3)_{t-1} Prior(a_4)_{t-1} Prior(a_5)_{t-1}}$

and accept the the vector theta at time t only if the $R$ is higher than 1 or than a random number between 0 and 1.

Can somebody give me an answer or a reference in which a case like this has been developed?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You actually have a single joint prior, which is a function of the parameter vector $\theta = [a_1, ..., a_d]$. If the parameters are treated independently, the prior factorizes into a product of the 'individual priors' that you mentioned. That is:

$$p(\theta) = \prod_{i = 1}^d p(a_i)$$

Classic Metropolis-Hastings looks the same whether you have a single parameter or multiple parameters; in the multi-parameter case, you just consider the parameter vector as a single object.

Let $\theta_t$ be the current parameter vector (at step $t$), $\theta'$ be a new candidate parameter vector drawn from the proposal distribution, and $D$ be the data. Calculate the ratio:

$$R_t = \frac{p(D \mid \theta') p(\theta')}{p(D \mid \theta_t) p(\theta_t)}$$

Accept $\theta'$ if $R_t \ge 1$, otherwise accept it with probability $R_t$.

Classic Metropolis-Hastings can be slow to converge in high dimensions. If this is a problem, more advanced techniques like Hamiltonian Monte Carlo can be used.

Comment: Thank you! Just a question, in case the Priors are not independent but correlated, how can I calculate $p(\theta)$ in five dimensions?

Comment: It's the prior, so you get to decide what it is. Presumably you'd have an expression for it that you can just evaluate (i.e. a function of the individual parameters).

Comment: the priors are derived from inference on other data sets.

Comment: If you want the prior to express dependence between the parameters, then you'd need a function that depends on multiple parameters, not just a set of marginal distributions for each separate parameter. So, you'd either have to infer this joint structure from your other data sets, or posit some kind of relationship yourself.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the existing thread, you could think of doing this using what are called piecewise or blockwise updates.

If you're considering the gaussian case and block updates you would have candidate values that are generated using a mean vector and a co-variance matrix and everything is accepted or rejected at once.

If you're however considering piecewise updates, you would then sample each parameter of interest independently and apply the acceptance criteria individually.

This link might help clarify
https://theclevermachine.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/mcmc-multivariate-distributions-block-wise-component-wise-updates/